# Iterate through a list that is a member of a greater list, while maintaining the format of the greater list in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like the end result to be a series of lists or sets containing the desired information from the listings on craigslist. I am getting tripped up when it comes to iterating through each data point in a listing, through the results of the numerous listings scraped containing the desired data.

Example URL: [Computers for sale listed in Sand Diego Somewhere](https://sandiego.craigslist.org/search/nsd/sss?query=computer)

Desired data format per listing: price, date, title, distance

The desired result would be one listing per line in the desired format, but it is either returning solely one listing and failing to return any others, or it is returning all the data retrieved from multiple listings for only the first data point. So, I am at a loss.

I have dabbled in working with arrays, but believe it can be done without arrays. I have tried using a dict, list, set, tuple, and list comprehensions. Currently, I am receiving no output, which I have not discovered the cause for as of yet.

Here is my code:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

########################################
# __   __        _      _    _         #
# \ \ / /_ _ _ _(_)__ _| |__| |___ ___ #
#  \ V / _` | '_| / _` | '_ \ / -_|_-< #
#   \_/\__,_|_| |_\__,_|_.__/_\___/__/ #
########################################

session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://sandiego.craigslist.org/search/nsd/sss?query=computer"
r = session.get(url)

########################
#   ___         _      #
#  / __|___  __| |___  #
# | (__/ _ \/ _` / -_) #
#  \___\___/\__,_\___| #
########################
def get_price():
    list_price = r.html.find("ul#search-results.rows > li.result-row > a.result-image.gallery > span.result-price")
    prices = []
    for a in list_price:
        price = a.text
        prices.append(price)
    return prices
        
def get_date():
    list_date = r.html.find("ul#search-results.rows > li.result-row > div.result-info > time.result-date")
    dates = []
    for b in list_date:
        date = b.text
        dates.append(date)
    return dates
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more efficient and cleaner method to acquire the same result, but a satisfactory result was achieved through understanding iterable, list comprehensions, and dict comprehensions.

I still receive a nasty error message on completion, `StopIteration`, but this can be ignored for my purposes. As long as it satisfies my needs.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10
# Craiglist Scraper

from requests_html import HTMLSession

########################################
# __   __        _      _    _         #
# \ \ / /_ _ _ _(_)__ _| |__| |___ ___ #
#  \ V / _` | '_| / _` | '_ \ / -_|_-< #
#   \_/\__,_|_| |_\__,_|_.__/_\___/__/ #
########################################

session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://sandiego.craigslist.org/search/nsd/sss?query=computer"
r = session.get(url)

########################
#   ___         _      #
#  / __|___  __| |___  #
# | (__/ _ \/ _` / -_) #
#  \___\___/\__,_\___| #
########################

ef snarp():
    list_price = r.html.find("ul#search-results.rows > li.result-row > a.result-image.gallery > span.result-price")
    list_date = r.html.find("ul#search-results.rows > li.result-row > div.result-info > time.result-date")
    list_title = r.html.find("ul#search-results.rows > li.result-row > div.result-info > h3.result-heading")
    list_distance = r.html.find("ul#search-results.rows > li.result-row > div.result-info > span.result-meta > span.result-tags > span.maptag")

    elements = (list_price, list_date, list_title, list_distance)

    taters = [[x.text for x in y] for y in elements]

    peter = iter(taters[0])
    deter = iter(taters[1])
    teter = iter(taters[2])
    leter = iter(taters[3])
    while len(next(peter)) > 0:
        p_want = "{ " + str(next(peter)) + ", " + str(next(deter)) + ", " + str(next(teter)) + ", " + str(next(leter)) + " }"
        print(p_want)
    else:
        print("No More")
        exit(0)

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    snarp()
```